# Simple security

Tags: php, html, security, passwords

I'm trying to build a webpage where the user has to answer a question to go further (a bit like a password I guess). How would I go about doing this?

I'm not worried about it being secure, as it's just a bit of fun.

For example, a question would be: "2+2=?".

The user would have to type the answer: "4" and click 'Submit' to proceed to a URL if correctly answered.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){
#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
}
}
?> 

<form action="http://somewhere.com/" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `POST` variables, your method is incorrect, being `GET` and will not work.

The methods must match `$_POST` for `method="POST"` and `$_GET` for `method="GET"`

And since your entire code is inside one page, your action needs to be `action=""`

Give this a try, tested.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){

echo "The number is correct.";
#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{

echo "Sorry, try again.";
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
  }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

You could also do it this way, to show the user that the correct answer was indeed `4`.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){

$answer=$_POST['answer'];

echo "The number is correct.";
echo "\n";
echo "The answer was in fact $answer";

#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{

echo "Sorry";
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
  }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

**To show a link** if the answer was correct, you could do it this way.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){

$answer=$_POST['answer'];

echo "The number is correct.";
echo "\n";
echo "The answer was in fact $answer";
echo "\n";
echo "<br>";
echo "You have access. " . "<a href='special_page.php'>Click here to go there now</a>";

exit;

#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{

echo "Sorry";
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
   }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

**To show the number** under the submit button after the correct number was entered, use the following:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){

$answer=$_POST['answer'];

echo "The number is correct.";
echo "\n";
echo "The answer was in fact $answer";

echo "<br>";
echo "You have access." . "<a href='page.php'>Click here to go there now</a>";

// exit;

#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{

echo "Sorry";
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
   }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

<?php echo "<br><br>" . $answer; ?>

</form>
```

---

**To automatically redirect** a user to another page or website, you can use the following:

This uses the [`header()`](http://www.php.net/header) function.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_POST['answer']) && $_POST['answer'] == 4){

$answer=$_POST['answer'];

header("Location: http://www.example.com/redirect.php");

exit;

#Right answer was given continue with submitting form
}else{

echo "Sorry, try again.";
#The wrong answer was given give an error message.
   }
}
?> 

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer"  placeholder="2+2=?">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

---

If you ever get an error message similar to `headers already sent by...`, then this will mean that you have output before headers.

An example error message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (**output started at /folder/file.php:10**) in **/folder/file.php** on **line 10**

If possible, do not put anything above `<?php` including a space, a tab, a cookie, HTML etc. This could also be caused by what is called a [`byte order mark`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (a.k.a. BOM) and your file needs to be saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

A quick fix is to use [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/ob_start) just under the opening `<?php` tag.

I.e.:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// content
```

Comment: That's brilliant, so how to I get it to go to a link when correct then? 

Alternatively, is there a way that I can get the echos to appear under above the submit button?

Comment: Indeed that is entirely possible. Give me a minute and I will add to my answer. @Joesruddock

Comment: Reload my answer, and look under "To show a link"... @Joesruddock

Comment: For the "link" addition, I added `exit;` after the link, which won't show the form after successful number entered. @Joesruddock - You can add it to the others like I did for the 3rd example, if you don't want the form to show up after success.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, look under my new edit under **"To show the number under the submit button...after the correct number was entered, use the following:"** @Joesruddock

Comment: And another option could be to **"automatically redirect a user to another page"** See new addition under `To automatically redirect` heading. @Joesruddock

Comment: You're very much welcome, was glad to help. I like to be concise and informative as possible :) I added a few more things near the end, that could some day happen. It's good to know these things ahead of time, should an error as shown under my new addition "`If you ever get an error message similar to..`" . @Joesruddock Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to store the question in session and then matched the answer.
2. make method = "POST"  in `<form action="http://somewhere.com/" method="GET">`

Comment: Store the question in the session and then matched the answer? Sorry, I'm not used to this stuff :D Thanks so far :D